# Fundamentals - How to show products?

Tags: magento-1.8

I am a magento beginner. I created a product group and a product for it.

[image]

Then I created a category and assigned the "Grouped product" to it.

[image]

Then I created a new page (kleber) and edited the home page to point to it.
The page is still empty though, how can I show all products from the cateogory (ID 4) on that page?

I added this widget to the page "kleber":

[image]
[image]

But it is not possible to specify the category id and the page stays empty

[image]

Comment: When you created the product did you make sure it was in stock, had stock and was available in your website

Comment: Im not sure how I can check this? How do I know if it is available in the website for instance?

Comment: When you create or edit a product there is a section called websites https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-websites.html

Comment: @Holly, Nope, there is nothing, see screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tbwW.png

Comment: @Holly, after setting the quantity and "in stock" it works, but the widget is not doing what I planned, it just shows all products instead of only the one from my category.